# how to handle notification in IE 11 , with selenium 3.12

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lu0n.png)

How to handle this type of notification 
i m using window 10 , IE 11.1088.15063.0 , selenium 3.12.0 jar

Answer (score 0):

You can use find element method to locate and click on the element. For example, if you want to click on `NO THANKS` button. Try the following.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='NO THANKS']")).click();
```

or if you want to click on YES button.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/span[text()='YES']")).click();
```

Comment: thank you... but suddenly it stop showing that notification. without using above commands.